# When to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have a question on Stack Overflow where all the answers contributed to the solution. No one person had the whole thing, so I didn't accept an answer (It was sort of a discussion where everyone came up with ideas and everyone benefited). Do you think I should just accept the person who helped with the biggest step even though everyone else helped a lot?

[For 2 numbers, how to test if one is an integer power of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846267/for-2-numbers-how-to-test-if-one-is-an-integer-power-of-the-other)

Comment: I'd probably give it to the answer which was the most thorough. Also, can you add a link to the question you're asking about?

Comment: Withhold it. Otherwise, it's just dirty, and you'll never get it back. OK, it's not really dirty and you can, of course, take it back. But withhold it anyway until someone formulates the complete solution even if just piecing it together like Voltron.    ...or just give it away, it's just a checkmark.

Comment: Alternatively, accept *none* of the answers and instead post your own answer that succinctly summarizes the solution (i.e., what you did and why it worked to solve the problem). That way, future viewers will find a complete, self-contained solution to their problem. You might mark this summary answer "community wiki" to (1) indicate that it was a collaborative effort, (2) encourage collaborative editing, and (3) opt out of earning from earning rep. But you don't have to.